# JS event delegation not working for some components

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

Here is my fiddle showing my code so far : http://jsfiddle.net/abhighosh18/dp240twL/1/

## Problem Description :

I am using `event-delegation` here, where on the click of a `div` I take the clicked div into an object and give user an option to give **title** to that div and then append that text to the div OR remove the component completely.

This is how I have used event delegation :

```
var obj1, obj2;

    $(document).on('click', ".comp1", function () {
        obj1 = $(this);
        console.log('Square clicked');
        $(".componentTitle").show();
        $(".btnSaveTitle").show();
        $(".btnRemove").show();
    });

    $(document).on('click', ".comp2", function () {
        obj2 = $(this);
        console.log('Circle clicked');
        $(".componentTitle").show();
        $(".btnSaveTitle").show();
        $(".btnRemove").show();
    });
```

Now the ***problem is,*** I have two shapes here : Square and Circle. Now the event fires properly for Circle - the text appends successfully . Now when I click on the square and save the title for it , the text is appended to the circle only.

This is how I append text to components :

```
 $(".btnSaveTitle").click(function () {
        var title1 = $(".componentTitle").val();

        if (obj1 !== undefined) {
            obj1.find(".label1 center").html(title1);
            obj1.attr("title", title1);
        }

        if (obj2 !== undefined) {
            obj2.append("<center>" + title1 + "</center>");
            obj2.attr("title", title1);
        }

        $(".btnRemove").hide();
        $(".componentTitle").hide();
        $(".btnSaveTitle").hide();
    });
```

Why is the event not delegated or why is the text not getting appended to the square component ?

**NOTE:** I am saving the style of the whole event plan via `$.POST` and entering the attributes to the DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code for appending to a ellipse is:

```
if (obj2 !== undefined) {
    obj2.append("<center>" + title1 + "</center>");
    obj2.attr("title", title1);
}
```

However, your code for appending to a rectangle is:

```
if (obj1 !== undefined) {
    obj1.find(".label1 center").html(title1);
    obj1.attr("title", title1);
}
```

If you change the `obj1.find()` call to be as the `obj2.append()` call for your ellipse code, it works with the same functionality.

---

To avoid text appending to each element if the title is changed, you can `empty()` it before you `append()`.

```
obj2.children('center').remove();
obj2.append("<center>" + title1 + "</center>");
```

---

To clear the text box after the save button is clicked, simply add a call to `val()` in the event handler for the button click,

```
$(".btnSaveTitle").click(function () {
    var title1 = $(".componentTitle").val();
    $(".componentTitle").val("");
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dp240twL/4/

Comment: In your fiddle there is one minor problem. When I edit text multiple times the original text persists. How do I remove old text and append it with new text ?

Comment: Also the text is getting appended to both the components after 2-3 times I have clicked on either component and tried to change the title

Comment: Re the first comment, I thought that was intended, it's how the original behaved. The text is appended because that's what you code does - it calls `append()`

Comment: Yes I forgot to add the edits. But how would I achieve this  ? should i empty the html or do `.val("");`??

Comment: I have tried `.empty()` before .. But that will not work. As doing that will remove all the `jquery-ui` classes for `resize()` and the resize will not work then

Comment: Okay, I understand. You'll want to call `children('center').remove()` then. That will remove only child elements of type `<center>`

Comment: I tried this : `obj1.children('center').remove();` .. But no luck .. Updated [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/abhighosh18/dp240twL/8/)

Comment: Your updated fiddle link still calls `obj1.empty()`, check it out now http://jsfiddle.net/dp240twL/9/, the change is in your save changes handler

Answer (score 3):

One thing you need to do is, when you store obj1

```
obj1 = $(this);
obj2 = undefined;
```

and

```
obj2 = $(this);
obj1 = undefined;
```

because, your appending code depends on object being "undefined".